# Permutation elections

Tags: permutations

During a local campaign eight republician and five democratic candidates are nominated for president.

a) If president to be one of thias candidates, how many possibilities are there for the eventual winner?

b) How many possibilities exist for a pair of candidates (one from each party) to oppose each other for the eventual election?

Comment: a) $C(8+5,1)=C(13,1)$ and 
b) $C(8,1)C(5,1)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer it will be useful. :)

Comment: My pleasure Noxob. ヅ